# Kendo UI Mobile MVVM - How to handle two list views that navigate to a single detail view?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have two `ListViews` (in separate views).  These views are bound to separate view-models but the `ListViews` contain the same entity type.  Both views allow the user to select an item and navigate to it's detail/edit view.

What do I need to do to share this detail view between the two list views?

Here is what I have tried:

**Assign the selected item to a property in the detail view's view-model**

This initially appeared to work but actually breaks Kendo MVVM.  Since the item is in the list view's view-model, assigning it to a property in another view-model causes problems.

**Refresh data in each view's show event**

While this almost works, it has a couple problems.  1) Getting fresh data all the time can be slow.  2) When saving changes in the detail view and navigating back to the list view, the save is async, so there is no guarantee that those changes will have been persisted before the call for ListView data.  This also negates one of the benefits of MVVM and observables.

**Share the view-model across views**

The examples I have seen that have a list and detail view, have both views sharing a view-model with a `selectedItem` property.  This is not possible in my particular case because I have two list views that navigate to the same detail view - not to mention that I prefer to have a separate view-model for each view so that the view-models don't become a huge mess.  Am I supposed to have all views share a single view-model?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could extract the observable model to a plain object model with the [toJSON()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observableobject#methods-toJSON) method, and then create a new observable model from it by wrapping it again. This should clear the existing bindings and avoids the conflicts you've found in your first approach.

```
var model = kendo.observable( otherModel.toJSON() );
```